# Search a row for matches

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm very new to Google Sheets and particularly using the Apps Script API to make functions for Sheets.

My goal is to search 3 cells in a row, and if two of three contain an 'X', the third which does not turns blue.

Currently the sheet has conditional formatting as follows:

- X = Green
- Empty = Red
- ? = Orange
- ! = Blue

So the intent is to change the `Empty` cell to `!` if the other two cells in the row are `X`.

Image for reference:

[image]

Essentially, I need a function which can check a range of cells for their contents, but I don't know how to properly use the API, if someone could give me a bit of help it would be greatly appreciated.

Note: This is NOT for a project of any sort, this is just for my friends and myself.

## Edit

My thoughts were to have the range as the function parameter (A1:C1 for instance) and then access the cell's data for the range and check them against each other. My issue is that I don't know how to use the API to get this data.

Comment: Are cells initially all empty? or is their default value a [?] . You could use a method that checks the onEdit event for the current cell, and then compare the cells in the same row...

Answer (score 1):

If the scenario mentioned before applies, you can use this method:

```
function checkRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var currentRow = activeCell.getRow();
  var currentCol = activeCell.getColumn();
  var allRange = ss.getRange("A1:C3");
  var activeValue = activeCell.getValue();
  var secondCell, thirdCell;

  if(activeValue == "x") 
  {
    if ( currentCol == 1 ) 
    {
      secondCell = allRange.getCell( currentRow, currentCol+1 );
      thirdCell = allRange.getCell( currentRow, currentCol+2 );
    } else if ( currentCol == 2 )
    {
      secondCell = allRange.getCell( currentRow, currentCol-1 );
      thirdCell = allRange.getCell( currentRow, currentCol+1 );
    } 
    else if ( currentCol == 3 )
    {
      secondCell = allRange.getCell( currentRow, currentCol-1 );
      thirdCell = allRange.getCell( currentRow, currentCol-2 );
    }
      if ( secondCell.getValue() == "x" && thirdCell.getValue() == "" ) 
      {
        thirdCell.setValue("!");
        thirdCell.setBackground("#00FFFF");
      } else if (thirdCell.getValue() == "x" && secondCell.getValue() == "" ) 
      {
        secondCell.setValue("!");
        secondCell.setBackground("#00FFFF");
      }
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is basically what I'm looking for, how do I get this function to run? Just write it into Custom Formula for every row?

Comment: No, just use the onEdit() trigger to call the method. Since it is checking the active cell, you don't have to worry about copying to every cell/row.

Comment: So I deleted my last comment, I got the onEdit() trigger function working, however my issue is that it's actually searching incorrectly, it needs to check the other columns on the row, it appears to be checking the other rows in the column.

I need it to check horizontally rather than vertically, I'm sorry if that wasn't clear.

Note: I've been trying to fix it myself, but it's behaving a little strangely. Editing the OP to show.

Comment: I'm getting the feeling that `secondCell` and `thirdCell` are null or something, as when I do `Logger.log(secondCell)` absolutely nothing happens. When I debug the function with Cell C highlighted it will say `Cell Reference out of range` at this point: `secondCell = allRange.getCell(currentRow, currentCol+1);` it does the same at secondCell for Cell E, but Cell D produces no errors.

Also, my range is C3:E600, is that okay or is that possibly what is causing the issues?

Comment: After reverting my modifications it runs...kind of properly. I dropped in some logs to track what's going on, here is a screen of the results: http://prntscr.com/8iz454

The code is identical to what you have, except I have increased the range from `A1:C3` to `C3:E600` as there are currently 300-350 entries and a good chance that it will expand.